# ADB Server is out of date, killing and restarting, for no reason

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I cannot resolve this issue:
I start an emulator, run adb devices and this happens, thus killing my emulator that was running -

> ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb devices
>
> **adb server is out of date.  killing...**
>   * daemon started successfully * List of devices attached  emulator-5554   offline

I am running 1.0.32 w/ Ubuntu 16. I have tried installing ADB once again, bit it does not help. Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have two adb servers running. The first is started by the emulator, probably from `$HOME/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` directory. The second adb server is when you run `adb` by hand.

The `adb` from the command line will try to connect to the server (started by the emulator). As the server is not what the client expects, it kills the server and starts his own.

Don't start the default `adb` by hand, run `$HOME/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb`. It will work.

Comment: I don't understand, I am already in the platform-tools directory when I run adb (which is already running from your explanation). how do I just pick up on the current adb server? Thanks!

Comment: You must run `./adb`, otherwise you will start `/usr/bin/adb` that is on `$PATH`, not `adb` on the directory you are.